# Search and replace and remember with which word the string has been replaced in regex

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

How do i find which substrings were replaced when `regex` replace was applied in javascript

```
Main string : abcSSSdeSSfghEEEijSSSkEEElmSSSnSSSEEEopEEE
```

**I want to replace all the minimal length substrings starting with 'SSS' and ends with 'EEE'. with .***

Upon applying a desired function i should get modified string

```
abc.*ij.*lmSSSn.*opEEE
```

and also the array for replaced strings as follows :

```
[ SSSdeSSfghEEE,  SSSkEEE, SSSEEE ]
```

How to efficiently implement the above desired function

Comment: You could start by writing code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript's `replace` lets us pass a function, so we can collect the matched values:

```
var arr = []
string.replace(/SSS.*?EEE/g, function (match) {
  arr.push(match)
  return '.*'
})
```

The `.*?` in the pattern insures it matches minimal length strings, and won't try to match from the first `SSS` to the last `EEE`.

Answer (score 3):

Pass a function as the second argument to String.replace:

```
var replacements = [];

var newString = oldString.replace(/*regex pattern here*/, function(match){
  replacements.push(match);
  return 'some replacement string';
});
```

Comment: Damn, you posted before I even started typing XD That's what I get for opening several tabs and working through them!

Comment: I also want to know the regex pattern for the same. i am newbie to regex stuffs. here http://regex101.com/r/yB0jH6 is what i am doing. but not getting success